# Error in PHP Mailer while executing in localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, phpmailer

As I am beginner in using PHPmailer trying to send mail in localhost (XAMPP) server. I included class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php file but I'm getting an error message "there is an error" To resolve this I changed gmail account IMAP settings as Enable and and allow less secure apps. 
But the problem has been not resolved. I get:

> Warning:fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\email-phpmailer\class\class.smtp.php on line 1023

Code I have Tried

```
<?php
//index.php

$error = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$subject = '';
$message = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
    return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if(empty($_POST["name"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Name</label></p>';
    }
    else
    {
        $name = clean_text($_POST["name"]);
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
        {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Email</label></p>';
    }
    else
    {
        $email = clean_text($_POST["email"]);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Invalid email format</label></p>';
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST["subject"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Subject is required</label></p>';
    }
    else
    {
        $subject = clean_text($_POST["subject"]);
    }
    if(empty($_POST["message"]))
    {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Message is required</label></p>';
    }
    else
    {
        $message = clean_text($_POST["message"]);
    }
    if($error == '')
    {
        require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->IsSMTP();                                //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';     //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
        $mail->Port = '587';                                //Sets the default SMTP server port
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
        $mail->Username = 'abc@gmail.com';                  //Sets SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'MyPass';                 //Sets SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                          //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
        $mail->From = $_POST["email"];                  //Sets the From email address for the message
        $mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];               //Sets the From name of the message
        $mail->AddAddress('xyz@gmail.com', 'its me');       //Adds a "To" address
        //$mail->AddCC($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);    //Adds a "Cc" address
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                           //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                            //Sets message type to HTML             
        $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];             //Sets the Subject of the message
        $mail->Body = $_POST["message"];                //An HTML or plain text message body
        if($mail->Send())                               //Send an Email. Return true on success or false on error
        {
            $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
        }
        else
        {
            $error = '<label class="text-danger">There is an Error</label>';
        }
        $name = '';
        $email = '';
        $subject = '';
        $message = '';
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Send an Email on Form Submission using PHP with PHPMailer</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8" style="margin:0 auto; float:none;">
                    <h3 align="center">Send an Email on Form Submission using PHP with PHPMailer</h3>
                    <br />
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                    <form method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" align="center">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using a very old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on [the gmail example provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) with it, which avoids several problems with the code you have here - quicker to do that than to tell you what you've done wrong!

Comment: I downloaded latest version as well used the gmail example code  but I am getting an error as Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\newPHPMailer\index.php on line 10

Comment: So read the readme - it tells you how to load the classes if you're not using composer. If you're a beginner, the time to learn [composer](https://getcomposer.org) is **now**, before you get into bad habits...

Comment: I have installed Package through Composer and working on simple example available in github page facing error as 2017-11-24 09:54:02 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Right, so now you have a different problem - but fortunately one that is covered extensively in the documentation that the error links you to (which is why it does so), and in many answers on Stack Overflow, so get reading and diagnose your problem.